# Bootstrapping Reclassified Layers of Two Species in QGIS for Suitable Area Overlap

Tags: qgis, maxent

I have a very surface-level knowledge and familiarity with QGIS.

I currently have 30 reclassified QGIS layers of suitable area based off of 30 MaxEnt individual runs for 2 different species. All layers are reclassified to binary, with a 1 being suitable and a 0 being unsuitable area. The binary values are based on a logistic threshold value, and every layer has its own threshold value.

I am trying to find a way to use bootstrapping to get a distribution of suitable area overlap between the two species, with these reclassified layers as input. For example, having a random selection of any of the 30 reclassified layers of species 1 being paired with any of the 30 reclassified layers of species 2, then (because of the bootstrap) this would be repeated in order to generate multiple estimates of area of overlap (an area generated for each combination of the bootstrap). I'm looking to randomly draw one MaxEnt run for one species (that has now been reclassified in QGIS) and find the area of overlap with a MaxEnt run from the other species (also now reclassified), and then do that a bunch of times: the bootstrap. I would then use all of those results from the bootstrap to generate a distribution curve.

I have not seen any way to do this in QGIS (or bootstrap at all).

Do you have any ideas or help for me?

I am using QGIS 3.16.1-Hannover on MacOS.

Comment: Bootstrap what? The assigned binominal, the probabilistic estimate? I cannot really think of a case where a parametric Bootstrap would be suitable. First, you are not accounting for error because the intrinsic model error is not being accounted for and is a notable component of uncertanty. Second, this is likey a nonparameric response, And third, MaxEnt assumes a complete probability distribution, much like a logistic function, making the uncertainty in the upper and lower bounds untenable. Whereas you can have a supported presence prediction the probabilities are mostly useless.

Comment: I am hoping to understand the distribution of areas of overlap of suitable habitat between two species. I want to get this distribution through bootstrapping. For example, having a random selection of any of the 30 reclassified layers of species 1 being paired with any of the 30 reclassified layers of species 2, then (because of the bootstrap) this would be repeated in order to generate multiple estimates of area of overlap (an area generated for each combination of the bootstrap). I would then use all of those results from the bootstrap to generate a distribution curve.

Comment: I think that you are looking for a Monte Carlo and not a Bootstrap. This would allow for the incorporation of an uncertainty term say, representing an error budget of the control models and evaluation of significance. I would still point out that a characteristic of MaxEnt models is that the lower tails of the distribution, in particularly, can exhibit random variation and above a certain probability threshold there is no difference in explained variation. As such, the prevalence is supported but there is not a difference between a probability of 0.65 and 0.85 given not confidence in bounds.

Comment: I completely forgot to add in that the layers have been reclassified to be binary (1 = suitable habitat, 0 = unsuitable habitat). I'm not sure if that alters your advice at all, and thank you so much for taking the time to leave such detailed responses! I added some more detail in the question itself in case that helps as I didn't want to run out of characters in the response text box.

Comment: Are you comfortable with pyqgis or R? This task will be much easier coding it up

Comment: I would definitely be more comfortable with R than pygis! However, if @LiamG you would recommend one over the other for a task like this let me know. And yes, the automation of the bootstrap is definitely ruined if you have to somehow do it manually : )